# Add action filter to partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know that I can add an action filter to a view by adding the following to an entire controller or a method inside of a controller:

```
[MyActionFilter] <-- Can be placed here...
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [MyActionFilter] <-- ...or here
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

But how would I add an action filter to just a partial view?

Would I need to declare the partial view in my parent controller, and apply it to just that method?

```
[MyActionFilter]
public ViewResult PartialView()
{
    return View("PartialView");
}
```

My partial view is referenced on multiple views, and so I don't want to have to add the above code to each controller.  Would placing the above code in a base controller class be acceptable?  That way each class that inherits the base controller would have that code available to it.

**UPDATE:**

I achieved the functionality I needed by doing the following, **but is that the proper way of doing it??**

I put the below method inside of my base controller, which all controllers inherit, so this is the only place which it will need to be declared.  I changed the `PartialView()` method from a `ViewResult` type to a `ActionResult` type and return a `PartialView`.

```
[MyActionFilter]
public ActionResult PartialView()
{
    return PartialView("PartialView");
}
```

I also had to change the actual reference in the views from `@Html.Partial("MyPartialView")` to `@Html.Action("MyPartialView")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action filters don't apply to views, they apply to action methods in a controller.

So by doing this:

```
[MyActionFilter]
public ViewResult MyPartialView()
{
    return View("PartialView");
}
```

you are setting up the ActionFilter `MyActionFilter` to be invoked whenever the `MyPartialView` action is called. So, to answer your question, if `MyPartialView` is the only action method that returns `"PartialView"`, then you won't need to apply it anywhere else.

But consider this Action on another controller:

```
public ViewResult AnotherWayToGetMyPartialView()
{
    return View("PartialView");
}
```

If you have another action method that returns `"PartialView"` then you would also need to add the ActionFilter there because it is a different **Action Method**, rather than view.

EDIT:

It won't matter whether your return type is `ActionResult` or `ViewResult`. A `ViewResult` is a child class of `ActionResult` so both will work and invoke the action filter. But, for the Action to be invoked and therefore the Action Filter too, rather than just the view, you need to make sure you are rendering the Action and not the view.. .so this:

```
@Html.Action("MyPartialView")
```

rather than this:

```
@Html.Partial("MyPartialView")
```

because that last one will bypass the action method.

Comment: So if I changed `MyPartialView()` from a `ViewResult` to an `ActionResult`, would that be acceptable?